# Is it possible to execute a goal seek if the outputs that need changing are controlled by multiple macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently writing a program that (currently has 5 macros) 1 is a macro to run all the others and the other 4 execute different parts of the program.

The first sheet has a number of inputs which all relate to different macros, once the input is run I have created a button which runs the main macro and then spits out the outputs (also shown on the first sheet).

What I want to do is goal seek how I need to change one of the inputs to ensure 2 outputs equal one another. I have tried:

```
Sub GoalSeek()
    Call RunMacros
    With Worksheets("Input1")
        .Range("I16").GoalSeek Goal:=.Range("I13").Value, _
         ChangingCell:=.Range("B8")
    End With
End Sub
```

However, it runs all the macros and THEN goal seeks, which it obviously reaches nothing and just gives up.

Is there a way to code that the macros need to be executed too to allow the goal seek to occur or is it too much?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds to me like the macros that are being executed by `RunMacros` need to be able to talk to each other in some way, rather than run independently of one another. Could you clarify exactly what it is you're trying to do, and maybe summarise the other macros and the role they play in this?

Comment: As already mentioned its unclear what you actually want to do. But if you want to execute the macros after the goalseek then use `Call RunMacros` after the with statement.